# How to make shrinked forecast for the extreme value?

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, regularization

Let me use made-up example:

> John loves running. He decided to run in his local half-marathon for
>   the first time in his life. He never measured exactly how fast he runs
>   the distance, but while running in his area he noticed that he's much
>   faster then other runners. Because of that, he assumes that he could be
>   as fast as the person who took second or third place in last year's
>   run. However, he also knows that from time to time runners from other
>   cities come to run in his local half-marathon and they could possibly
>   be outliers comparing to the sample he noticed on the streets during his
>   daily runs.

So John would like to make a forecast about his time based on the third fastest time in last year's run, but he'd also want to take into consideration timings for other runners, so to correct if the first three timings were outliers that came to the run from the other cities (e.g. professional runners that came because of the prizes). What would be the best way for him to make forecast given the assumption that he is somewhere close to the third best runner, but at the same time correcting for the possible outliers..?

Take as example the data below showing running times from some random half-marathon.

```
c(78, 78, 83, 89, 94, 95, 95, 96, 97, 97, 98, 99, 101, 101, 101, 
101, 103, 103, 105, 105, 106, 107, 107, 107, 107, 108, 108, 108, 
109, 109, 109, 109, 110, 111, 111, 113, 113, 113, 114, 115, 115, 
115, 116, 117, 118, 118, 118, 119, 119, 120, 122, 123, 123, 123, 
124, 125, 125, 125, 125, 126, 127, 127, 127, 130, 130, 131, 133, 
133, 133, 134, 135, 139, 139, 140, 141, 142, 142, 146, 146, 151, 
153, 154, 154, 155, 156, 156, 156, 156, 158, 165, 165, 169, 169, 
185)
```

As you can see on the plot below, the four fastest runners are slightly outlying. How to make forecast that takes into consideration the best runners but correcting for how much they are outlying from the ordinary ones?

[image]

Comment: It's pretty safe to assume the running time is independent from the other runners.  So you're really asking for how many runners in the (self selected) sample will be above "John's time".  Are these elements still relevant to your actual problem?  Or are you interested in more abstract, general approach?

Comment: @probabilityislogic the problem is simplified and provided as example, I'm looking for a general approach and possible references. It can be re-stated as you did, but notice that I'm interested in the expected timing - so it possibly could be something between the highest "non-extreme" and the extreme timings (imagine big discrepancy where the forecast is somewhere between 4. and 5. runner).